# How to save and load elements to/from a layer in correct z-order?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine

I copy elements from one layer to another like this:

```
IGraphicsContainer container = _mapControl.Map as IGraphicsContainer;
IGraphicsContainerSelect containerSelect = container as IGraphicsContainerSelect;

containerSelect.SelectAllElements();
IEnumElement enumElement = containerSelect.SelectedElements;
enumElement.Reset();

IElement element = enumElement.Next();
while (element != null)
{
  int zorder = 0; // How to get this?
  layerContainer.AddElement(element, zorder);
  element = enumElement.Next();
}
```

This works fine so far but I obviously like to preserve the element's zorder. I tried to get the zorder with `graphicsContainer.GetElementOrder(enumElements)` which returns an object (COM object). Well, but what to do with that one, eh?

How can I get the zorder of an element?

**Update**
The `enumElement` is already in the correct order (Thanks, Kirk). I now took a deeper look into it. 
The elements get saved in the correct z-order, but when I load the layer from file (with `IMapControl.AddLayerFromFile`) they appear in reversed z-order every time.
I tried to save them with reversed z-order but on the loaded layer they still appear in the wrong z-order.

How can I load the layer with the elements in correct z-order?

Comment: Did you try element.Geometry.Envelope?

Comment: Have you been able to confirm that sometimes the order of the elements returned by enumElement.Next() is not based on z-order?

Comment: Kirk: Good tip. I didn't know they are in the correct order. But still there is a glitch somewhere (see Update).

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what the `Envelope` should help me with that? Can you give more detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. `AddElements` [ignores](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000005q8000000) the z-order. `SelectedElements` is in the correct z-order, but you have to add them with `AddElements` in reversed order (I already tried this, but with use of the - ignored - z-order parameter).

One more hint: When one selects an element in the UI and changes the z-order, the element needs to be unselected before the change gets saved, so I do `containerSelect.UnselectAllElements();` first.

```
containerSelect.UnselectAllElements(); // see hint
containerSelect.SelectAllElements();
IEnumElement enumElement = containerSelect.SelectedElements;
enumElement.Reset();
IElement element = enumElement.Next();
List<IElement> elemente = new List<IElement>();
while (element != null)
{
  elemente.Add(element);
  element = enumElement.Next();
}
for (int j = elemente.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
{ // add in reversed order
  layerContainer.AddElement(elemente[j], 0); // z-order parameter is ignored 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way neither.. but one other solution you can try is through copy and paste (which does seem to maintain the zorder).

```
            IMxDocument mxDoc = ArcMap.Document as IMxDocument;
            IViewManager vm = mxDoc.FocusMap as IViewManager;
            ISelection sel = vm.ElementSelection; 

            sel.Copy();

            //Get to another dataframe/map
            IMap map = mxDoc.Maps.get_Item(1);
            mxDoc.ActiveView = (IActiveView)map; 
            IViewManager vm2 = map as IViewManager;
            ISelection sel2 = vm2.ElementSelection;

            sel2.Paste();
```